# php curl certificate validation failing but only on one machine

Tags: php, validation, curl, ssl-certificate

This is the code I am running:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://core.spreedly.com/v1/payment_methods/P94ca6iTsZ4fHwiP7j8tmG17fH1/retain.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/home/scrutinizer/build/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/cacert.pem');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($res);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

And it produces this output:

```
bool(false)
string(125) "server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /home/scrutinizer/build/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/cacert.pem CRLfile: none"
```

But only on this server! When I run it on another machine, same setup - ubuntu 14.04 LTS - same versions of php, curl, etc, it runs perfectly. What would cause the certificate validation to fail for one server, when it works for another?

Comment: Have you have added cacert.pem file on server?

Comment: @BhumiShah no, that question is specific to git - mine is specific to php. I already tried running the curl call manually from the command line, same settings, and it worked - so it is only happening within php.

Comment: @BhumiShah I'm specifying the cacert file via CURLOPT_CAINFO, which overrides the server file, and I've confirmed that there are no permission/readability issues with the file.

Comment: have you tried with curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); ?

Comment: @BhumiShah Yes, I get an error message saying that it no longer accepts a value of 1 and I should use 2 instead.